Как RSD файл, полученный с эхолота Garmin, преобразовать в CSV файл?
Я произвёл эхолотную съёмку на реке с помощью эхолота Garmin, исходные файлы получились в формате RSD, нужно их преобразовать в формат CSV, для дальнейшей обработки в Autocad. Специализированная программа Basecamp не даёт сделать экспорт в CSV. Пробовал конвертировать, пишет, что неизвестный формат данных. Посоветуйте, как быть?
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/1ZraVCet9vHTQg

"rsd" - это просто три буквы латинского алфавита. вы бы ссылку на содержимое файла приложили - было бы больше шансов получить какой-то полезный совет. p.s. хотя самый верный путь - обратиться к производителю приобретённого вами прибора.


Пишут, что программа таки экспортирует в .csv. 2. Сам формат .rsd описан в https://www.memotech.franken.de/FileFormats/Garmin_RSD_Format.pdf


Как заметил в комментарии @ddd, есть документация по структуре файлов.
На гитхабе есть проект rsd_decoder. Вы можете им воспользоваться. Для примера, я скомпилировал эту программу и протестировал на ваших файлах.
Скачать собранную программу можно по ссылке: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/itF-zF_OCPoZzg. Результат работы программы, на некоторых файлах, можете посмотреть по ссылке: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/_K5IKuSjW_n9Ug.
Для удобства, лучше положить RSD файл в ту же папку, где находится exe файл. Результат работы будет в этой же папке, в файле test.csv. Программа работает медленно! На моём ноутбуке файл Sonar000.RSD (размером 45 МБ) обрабатывался больше 10 минут, наберитесь терпения.
